# Reset navigation without redux

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Currently, as far as I know `reset` in `react-navigation` is done by dispatching a redux action of `NavigationActions.reset();`

Console logging `this.props.navigation` shows a reset function, but if I try to use it as `this.props.navigation.reset('Home')`, it throws me an error `newStackActions.map` is not a function.

Can we reset the whole navigation without using redux? There should be such functionality, I guess I can't find it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use [StackActions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset) to reset a particular stack, and dispatch it using navigation's **internal dispatcher**

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Comment: thanks, though this solves my query. I'm still curious about the `reset` method available in the `this.props.navigation` object? Any clue how does that work?

Comment: It used to be there in previous versions, but as per the docs only this method is documented.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, after trying out some methods. `replace` seems to work just fine.

`this.props.navigation.replace(ScreenName)` replaces your current screen to the specified screen without any increment to the screen stack, essentially you just switch screens over.

I'll just leave it here in case anyone needs help.

**EDIT**

Note - In case anyone is confused, `replace` does not mimic the behaviour of a `reset` function.

`replace` just replaces your current active screen  or the topmost screen on the stack with the given screen whereas

`reset` essentially wipes off your whole navigation history and creates a new navigation object based on the screens references you provide. In other words you can essentially create a navigation stack full of screens you never visited. (not sure how it is possible ;))